# Calculating the minutes since midnight

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Have run into more of a maths problem than code. So far have programmed to retrieve the local time, print the local time as "Current Time: " and then programmed the variables to print "Number of minutes since midnight: ".
looks like this

```
import time
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print("Current Time: ",current_time)
hour = time.strftime("%H")
minute = time.strftime("%M")
print ("Number of minutes since midnight: ",int(hour)*60+int(minute))
```

so my output is

```
Current Time:  22:16:15
Number of minutes since midnight:  1336
```

Except a quick google search tells me it's closer to 2,777 minutes since midnight.

This is my first program, so if you're wondering why I want to know how many minutes since midnight it is at any given time without JFGI, I just do. It's been a fun problem to solve so far, and I would hate to leave it unfinished because I don't know the maths I need to know yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since there are only 1,440 minutes in a day, your Google search appears to be nonsense.  Did you even try to verify this with a calculator?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I just edited your post to fix the formatting, among other things. Please read the [Markdown help](/editing-help) to learn how to properly format code blocks. And check out [ask] if you want tips on asking a good question.

Comment: @Tim You're right. If I Google `how many minutes since midnight`, the result is 2,494 minutes for the period starting Apr **5** at 12 am, not Apr 6.

Comment: It appears to me that whatever site you used added an extra day for no apparent reason. `1336 + 1440 = 2776`. No clue why that is.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I did calculate it, but I know my maths can be faulty.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the signposting, and the edits! I'll look into those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is actually working as intended!

One quick recommendation for an improvement though:

When you call

```py
t = time.localtime()
```

You're storing the current time in the variable `t`, but then when you later call

```py
hour = time.strftime("%H")
minute = time.strftime("%M")
```

you are actually asking the program to fetch the system clock time again twice, rather than using the already stored time value you have in `t`.

You could instead do the following and access the hour and time values from the `t` object directly.

```py
import time
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print("Current Time: ", current_time)
print ("Number of minutes since midnight: ",int(t.tm_hour)*60+int(t.tm_min))
```

I hope you're enjoying your first steps into programming!

Answer (score 0):

I believe whatever you googled was incorrect, I tried this out and also got 1336.

```py
current_time = "22:16:15"
hrs, mins, _ = current_time.split(":")
since_midnight = int(hrs) * 60 + int(mins)
```

The total number of minutes in a day is 1440, so it clearly cant be more than that.